# R "Error: unexpected symbol in if"

Tags: r

For the life of me, I can't find an answer online to my very basic problem trying to execute an `if` statement. Any help greatly appreciated.

data:

```
Id,mo.year,
123,201102
436,201101
129,201302
```

(Both variables are character)

Code:

```
if(data$mo.year IN('201101','201102')) {data$year=1}
```

Results in:

```
Error: unexpected symbol in "if (data$mo.year IN"

if(data$mo.year IN('201201','201202')) {data$year=2}
if(data$mo.year IN('201301','201302')) {data$year=3}
```

Yields same errors.

Suggestions as to what I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: There is no R command `IN`; I think you are looking for `data$mo.year %in% c('201201','201202')`.

Comment: Ah yes. You're right, but when I run it with %n% I get the same error, this time indicating that there is an unexpected comma.

Comment: I mean when I run it with %in% not %n%

Comment: Did you add the `c` to `('201201','201202')`? You have to concatenate vectors, you can't just list values inside of parentheses.

Comment: I did that and it generated the warning message that the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used (seems more like an error as it populates the same value for year to all rows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you just need `ifelse`, the vectorized version of an `if` statement:

```
Df <- data.frame(
  Id=c('123','436','129'),
  mo.year=c('201102','201101','201302'),
  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
##
Df$year <- ifelse(
  Df$mo.year %in% c('201101','201102'),
  1,
  ifelse(
    Df$mo.year %in% c('201201','201202'),
    2,3))
##
> Df
   Id mo.year year
1 123  201102    1
2 436  201101    1
3 129  201302    3
```

Assuming you are just using the fourth digit of the `mo.year` column to generate your value, you could also do something like this, which is a little more concise:

```
Df$year <- as.numeric(
  gsub(
    "(201)(\\d)(\\d+)","\\2",Df$mo.year))
```